# How is this command involving 'find' and a 'here string' being executed?

Tags: bash

What is going on with this line?

```
echo <<< find * -maxdepth 0 -type f
```

I expected a list of file names from the current directory. Instead I got that plus `-maxdepth 0 -type f` at the end.

I don't understand how this command is being executed. If I can use parentheses to denote execution order, I would expect the following

```
echo <<< (find * -maxdepth 0 -type f)
```

where the output would be only the file names

or possibly

```
echo <<< (find * ) -maxdepth 0 -type f
```

where the output would be all file names in all subdirectories followed by `-maxdepth 0 -type f`.

Neither are reality, and I don't how the chain of execution could be such that produces the output.

So, my question is, how is this command executing, and how can I change it to have the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

I/O redirection operators can be put anywhere in a command line. Only the first word after one of these operators is used, the rest are just ordinary arguments to the command. So your command is equivalent to:

```
echo * -maxdepth 0 -type f <<< find
```

Since `echo` just echoes its arguments and doesn't read from standard input, the here-string can be ignored, so it's equivalent to:

```
echo * -maxdepth 0 -type f
```

The wildcard `*` is expanded to all the files in the current directory, so it echoes all those filenames followed by `-maxdepth 0 -type f`.

You shouldn't be using a here-string, since `echo` doesn't read input; you can use command substitution:

```
echo $(find * -maxdepth 0 -type f)
```

or just:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type f
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were expecting the output of `echo "$(find * -maxdepth 0 -type f)"`. `echo` ignores standard input. I think what happens is this:

1. The here-string sends *just the first word*, `find`, to the standard input of `echo`, which discards it. To send the whole right side, you'd have to quote

   ```
   echo <<< 'find * -maxdepth 0 -type f'
   ```

   which actually has zero output, because now everything is thrown away.
2. What's left is

   ```
   echo * -maxdepth 0 -type f
   ```

   resulting in the output you're seeing.

To get your expected output, just drop the `echo` and `<<<`:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type f
```

or, maybe better as the shell doesn't have to expand anything (includes dotfiles and prepends results each with `./`, though):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Comment: The last command needs to be `-maxdepth 1`, because the `.` directory itself is depth 0, and it has to recurse into the directory to get the filenames.

Comment: It will also prefix all the filenames with `./`.

Comment: Another difference: it will return all the dot-files, `find *` won't.